# Dynamic Outputs for MSBuild Custom Task in VS 2015

Tags: msbuild

I've been trying to create a custom build task in VS2015 for the message compiler - mc.exe.  You may realise how little documentation there is to support this sort of customisation.

I decided on the XamlTaskFactory approach based on the masm and lc extensions that came with VS. I've created the props, targets and UI xml files.

My first problem was to do with the Xaml task itself. I kept getting error MSB(*can't remember*) with a nice red herring saying the task was not found, etc.... After weeks of trial and error, (eventually downloading the MSBuild source and inspecting it), I got MSBuild/VS to cooperate when I *removed* the property defaults from the UI xml file - but that's another story, now addressed, and time permitting I'll write the whole experience up.

The problem I am still facing is the Outputs from the task. mc.exe generates (for my purposes) three outputs: a header file; a resource file; and a bin file.  The problem is that the names and paths of these files DEPEND on the options selected by the user in the property sheet.

The ItemDefinitionGroup in the props file sets defaults for the UI, defines the XamlTask commands template, and the Outputs item.

I had initially set the Outputs to be generated here, constructing them using parameters set in the UI property sheet. I soon realised that this wasn't going to work because the evaluation order in MSBuild meant that no matter what I did, anything done here has already been set in stone, and won't be effected by changes set in the UI property sheet.

I banged my head for another week, but could not find a way to modify the Outputs metadata in such a way as to allow me to incorporate user changes set through the UI.

So I came up with the idea of using properties to manage the Outputs. I created four properties to represent the Outputs: one each for the header, resource and bin files, and one to represent the entire Outputs property itself (concatenating each file with a semicolon), and then used the last $(MessageCompileOutputs) as the Outputs parameter for the task.

The three properties representing the individual files included transformation (@() and %()) operators, so as to defer evaluation to the Evaluation/Build phases. An ugly solution, but it allows incremental builds and works fine.

Except for TLog....  As the Outputs consist of strings using transformations, when I try to WriteLinesToFile to the appropriate TLog file, IT DOESNT expand the string, and so VS is looking for files that are never going to be there, and so the project will never appear up to date.

At the moment I've just left out TLog completely - the downside is that the VS Clean target doesn't work. However incremental builds do.

While it would be nice to get TLog to work, I've pretty much given up the battle as being *good enough* (something which I very rarely do). But in my last desperate hope, I thought I'd try posting here.

Any help, thoughts, constructive criticism, etc. would be very much appreciated. I'd be more than happy to upload the source (three files), but haven't a clue as how to do so.

[edit]

Guess my first and foremost question is "how can I set the Outputs metadata using the selected options in the UI property page in such a way to allow TLog to work"?

Second question is - is there a better/canonical way to do this? Meaning - how can you set a Task's outputs dynamically depending on the parameters selected in the UI property page. I can't possibly be the only person that has tried to do this...

Rick

Here is minimal code - enough to (hopefully) get the idea across, cut out lots to make it as short as possible.

XML file (MessageCompile.xml) chopped to keep code down

```
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions ...
  <!-- Content Type -->                          
  <ItemType, <ContentType, <FileExtension...

  <Rule   Name="MessageCompile", ....

    <Rule.DataSource>
      <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="MessageCompile" HasConfigurationCondition="false" />  <!-- On Purpose - global is easier, per config is just painful. -->
    </Rule.DataSource>

    <Rule.Categories>
      <Category Name="General"        DisplayName="General" />
      <Category Name="Command Line"   DisplayName="Command Line"  Subtype="CommandLine" />
    </Rule.Categories>

    <more stuf...................=""/>

    <StringProperty       Name="HeaderFolder"
                          DisplayName="Header Folder"
                          Description="Specifes the folder into which you want the compiler to place the generated header file. The default is the current directory."
                          Category="General"
                          Switch="-h &quot;[value]&quot;"
                          Subtype="folder"
                          />

    <StringProperty       Name="HeaderFile"
                          DisplayName="HeaderFile"
                          IncludeInCommandLine="False"
                          Visible="False"
                          />
  </Rule>
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

Props file (MessageCompile.props)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MessageCompileHeaderFileName   >@(MessageCompile->'%(HeaderFolder)'\MessageCompile->'%(Filename)').h</MessageCompileHeaderFileName>
    <MessageCompileResourceFileName >@(MessageCompile->'%(ResourceFolder)'\MessageCompile->'%(Filename)').rc</MessageCompileResourceFileName>
    <MessageCompileBinFileName      >@(MessageCompile->'%(ResourceFolder)'\MessageCompile->'%(Filename)').bin</MessageCompileBinFileName>
    <MessageCompileOutputs          >$(MessageCompileHeaderFileName);$(MessageCompileResourceFileName);$(MessageCompileBinFileName)</MessageCompileOutputs>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <MessageCompile>
      <CustomerBit            >true</CustomerBit>
      <Verbose                >false</Verbose>
      <HeaderFolder           >Generated</HeaderFolder>
      <ResourceFolder         >Generated</ResourceFolder>
      <UseInputFileNameForBin >true</UseInputFileNameForBin>
      <BinFileNameLanguage    >MSG00409</BinFileNameLanguage>
      <CommandLineTemplate    >mc.exe [AllOptions] [AdditionalOptions] [Inputs]</CommandLineTemplate>
      <ExecutionDescription   >Compiling message resource %(Identity)</ExecutionDescription>
    </MessageCompile>
 </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Targets file (MessageCompile.targets)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="MessageCompile">
      <Targets>_MessageCompile</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <UsingTask  TaskName="MessageCompile"
              TaskFactory="XamlTaskFactory"
              AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core"
              >
    <Task>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml</Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target     Name="_MessageCompile"
              BeforeTargets="CustomBuild;ResourceCompile"
              Condition="'@(MessageCompile)' != ''"
              Inputs="%(MessageCompile.Identity);$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
              Outputs="$(MessageCompileOutputs)"
              DependsOnTargets="_SelectedFiles"
              >

    <ItemGroup Condition="'@(SelectedFiles)' != ''">
      <MessageCompile Remove="@(MessageCompile)" Condition="'%(Identity)' != '@(SelectedFiles)'" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MessageCompile_tlog   Include="@($(MessageCompileOutputs))" Condition="'$(MessageCompileOutputs)' != '' and '%(MessageCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'">
        <Source>@(MessageCompile, '|')</Source>
      </MessageCompile_tlog>
    </ItemGroup>

    <WriteLinesToFile   Condition="'@(MessageCompile_tlog)' != '' and '%(MessageCompile_tlog.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true' and false"
                        File="$(TLogLocation)MessageCompile.write.1u.tlog"
                        Lines="^%(MessageCompile_tlog.Source);$(MessageCompileHeaderFileName);$(MessageCompileResourceFileName);$(MessageCompileBinFileName)"
                        Encoding="Unicode"
    />

    <Message            Importance="High"  Text="%(MessageCompile.ExecutionDescription)" />

    <MessageCompile     Condition="'@(MessageCompile)' != '' and '%(MessageCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'"
                        CommandLineTemplate="%(MessageCompile.CommandLineTemplate)"
                        Inputs="%(MessageCompile.Identity)"
                        CustomerBit="%(MessageCompile.CustomerBit)"
                        Verbose="%(MessageCompile.Verbose)"
                        HeaderFolder="%(MessageCompile.HeaderFolder)"
                        ResourceFolder="%(MessageCompile.ResourceFolder)"
                        UseInputFileNameForBin="%(MessageCompile.UseInputFileNameForBin)"
                        BinFileNameLanguage="%(MessageCompile.BinFileNameLanguage)"
                        SpecifiedBinFileName="%(MessageCompile.SpecifiedBinFileName)"
                        />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: 1) what is your actual question 2)it would help if you could post a minimal sample of what your current msbuild code looks like (just assuming your question is about that, else post other minimal code which can be used to reproduce the problem)

Comment: Guess my first and foremost question is "how can I set the Outputs metadata using the selected options in the UI property page". I'll try to put together minimal code, and add to the original question.